Mermaid who spent time in an orphanage
It was a Spanish TV show around 10.  I remember this show used to come on the same channel as ruby. 
It was all about this girl who was an orphan and the orphanage was located on an island. The girl was a mermaid and I believe her name was Anna not really sure her fake dad that adopted her lived on a boat or something to that degree and there was an adult mermaid also. One of her best guy friends was name Gudo I think. I believe they fell in love until she find out that he was her brother. I think the main key points were that she lived in an orphanage for a while and was a mermaid.
It was about ten years ago or around that time, I'm 19 now and I believe I used to watch it when I was about 6 to 8 years old. The show was live action. Thank you guys in advance for trying to help out. Can anyone identify this TV series?

"around 10" You mean the hour? Or that you were 10? (Do you remember the approximate year, BTW? And was it live action or animated?)

It was about ten years ago or around that time, I'm 19 now and I believe I used to watch it when I was about 6 to 8 years old.The show was live action

It all sounds like the Mexican show Amy, la niña de la mochila azul from 2004.

"Amy The girl with the blue schoolbag" is a soap opera for kids. As a baby, Amy was rescued from the sea by Captain Matías and his wife Perla, who later dies, but Captain Matías promises his wife to take care of Amy. She lives on a ship with her step-father, who after his wife's death is destroyed, keeps losing everything, almost has no money and is about to lose the last thing he has left: his ship. Amy is a mischievous girl and dresses like a boy. Her real father is a millionaire Octavio who has lost his newborn baby in the hurricane and is searching for "him" (as he thinks it was a baby boy). He will meet Amy and they will become friends, without knowing that the "boy" he is searching for in reality is Amy. She will also meet a nice boy Raul with whom she will fall in an innocent love. There is also an evil Carlota who hates orphans, but uses them to get donations and with this money buys herself fine jewelry. In order to get more donations she needs to get more orphans, and she is now after Amy, whose origin is in question...

Amy's mother is really a mermaid and one of her male friends is called Gato. Here's the intro:



